# Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency

Using v2.73, cycles and a very simple scene: an array of cubes, no big deal.
[image]

If I set the shader's material to transparent, the cubes in the foreground do become transparent but those far away in the back do not disappear completely and this strange dark *things* appear (visible in rendered mode and in final renders)

[image]

I've played with the clipping distance on the viewport and camera, but I can't figure out how to make those *ghosts* go away...

Comment: crank up the transmission in light paths in render tab

Comment: it's transparency not transmission sorry, try again

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18857/599

Comment: I panicked when I saw you asked this question and felt so relieved after scrolling down and seeing an accepted answer!

Comment: Me as well hit the panick button, good grief thanks

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Go to Light Paths under the Render Tab and turn up the Max amount of [transparent bounces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/light_paths.html) until you have enough for every cube.

[image]

For 2.8* set the Transmission bounces in the Render section>Light Paths>Max Bounces

[image]

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: transmission or transparency?

Comment: Although that answer has lots of upvotes, it mixes up _Transparency_ and _Transmission_ bounces, especially because when it says that from Blender 2.8* upwards you should increase the _Transmission_ bounces. But that's wrong, this wouldn't help in this case. Also it doesn't give hints on the dependencies between _Total_ and _Transmission_ bounces. In the screenshot they both have a value of 12, which is okay. But if 12 wasn't enough, increasing only the _Transmission_ bounces won't make a difference - whereas _Transparency_ (which is what's needed here) would work when increased.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the *Max Bounces* setting for *Transparent* bounces under *Light Paths* in the *Render Properties*.

As it seems, you have a value of 0 there. I would rather suggest setting it to a much higher value like 64 or even 128. It doesn't increase the render time very much but you can avoid black artifacts when too many transparent objects are overlapping themselves. Also black artifacts in smoke simulations are much less likely to happen.

The problem doesn't occur in *Eevee* since it's not a raytracing engine and doesn't use the *Light Paths* settings for bounces etc. The background is still transparent since it is not "bouncing off" rays so it's not limited to that setting.

It is not necessary to increase the *Total* bounces, since *Transparent* bounces are independent from the *Total* amount while the other values are not. You'll find it here:

[image: transparent bounces]

Here is an example: When you have one plane with transparency in front of another object e.g. a sphere, the object behind it will be black in the transparent areas just like in your screenshot, because the *Transparent* bounces are set to 0.

[image: transparent 0]

If you now simply increase the value to 1, the sphere will no longer be black behind the plane. But if you put a second plane in the scene, the sphere only shows correct behind the one or the other plane. Where they are overlapping it has turned black again, because there are 2 transparent layers. You can imagine that using small values will quickly give bad results for example on tree objects holding lots of leaves with transparency.

[image: transparent 1]