# blender cycles renders alpha black but shows up fine in material tab

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

[image]

As you can see it shows up just fine in material mode, so that must mean my node set-up is right.

I also noticed that the the tree and bushes don't have this problem.

Is it a shadow issue?

[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hik5kgwu66lln3/blend.blend?dl=0)

(It may not have packed correctly)

Comment: Looks like you need to increase the number of transparent bounces. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42023/599

Comment: YAY THANKS! can't believe this didn't cross my mind orz