# Strange blocks appearing in my render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Created a tree using the sapling add-on, and when I render it, strange blocks start appearing all over the image.
The leaves are simple rectangles, with a Velvet material applied to them.
[image: Render contains strange blocks appearing randomly]

Comment: Increase transparent light bounces?

Comment: Do you have any other addons enabled which may cause this?

Comment: Nice render btw

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026