# Multiple planes with transparent PNG textures render black

Tags: texturing, particles

I am trying to create a forest effect, however, the alpha from the trees in the background is not working properly in front views. Any idea about how to solve this? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: increase the number of transparency bounces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent textured planes produce black artifacts](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects/27719#27719