# How do i get rid of these black shadows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, light, shadows

I'm trying to render an animation about this children's crib. Essentially I'm creating a "How to install" guide as the printed one is dated and difficult to understand.

Using Blender 2.78 in cycles, I can render my object just fine. As I'll want to show where certain screws go and how the parts slot together, I want to use transparencies.

First I combined the diffuse shader with a transparent shader through a mix shader. At 50% and at 100% transparent I get these results.
[image]
So essentially if I tried to make the whole object transparent, I get these "shadows" remaining on the render.
So I decided to focus on one panel. I went 100% transparent for the Grey color and it works fine. When I try to do the same with the chrome color, the color or hue disappears but again i'm left with a kind of shadow from where the objects where. [image]
I've removed doubles, made sure nothing is overlapping but I'm still stuck. Think it has something to do with shadows or the way I'm using the shaders. Anyways I fairly stuck and would appreciate any help. Thanks, Adam.

It won't let me post another pic yet as I'm new to the forum but my settings are as follows:
Transparency Max:4 Min:1, Bounces Max:4 Min:1, Diffuse:4, Glossy:4, Transmission:4, Volume:0, 
Shadows: Checked, Reflective Caustics: Checked, Refractive Caustics: Not checked, Filter Glossy:1.0,

Comment: Looks like some of the rays are being terminated before reaching a light source or lit surface: how many transparency bounces did you set? could you show you light path panel?

Comment: increase the number of **transparency bounces**: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects/27719#27719

Answer (score 2):

[image]

By increasing the Transparency Max from 4 to 24 (with some trial and error), I was able to successfully eliminate the all of the shadows from my animation. I originally tried increasing the Bounces Max to 48 with no success, so I dropped it back to 4, then increased the Transparency Max amount and everything worked.

Thanks to everyone for their help and suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could always turn off shadows under the object tab:

[image]

[image]

Tried that but nothing changed. I have 12 (yep) lamps in the scene because I need the highlights/shadows so I'm thinking it has to do with light getting trapped there or the "shadows" are baking there. When I turn of the shadows I get this result which is not what I'm after. It eliminates all the shadows running across the centre board and doesn't remove the "shadows".
[image]

Comment: are you just turing off the shadows on the front panel object? Because you should still get the shadows on the other 3 walls

Comment: The picture above has both the front panel and the back panels with the shadows turned off. When I render just the front panel with shadows off, nothing changes. I've tried increasing the Max Bounces to 48 under Light Paths, also tried checking Transparent Shadows under Material/Settings but nothing. I've also changed the entire front panel to the same material but that didn't help.