# Why are my leaves dissappearing and turning black

Tags: materials

So I have a leaf material with transparent alpha, and I used a particle system to put it on an empty tree to make it look like it has leaves. The texture I used had a transparent background so I used a transparent material to make it actually transparent.

[image][image]
[image]

But this is what happens when I convert the particle system and join it with the tree. It's so annoying, it's happened once before when I tried to use the array modifier to an image with a transparent background and the background turns black despite having the right material. What do I do?

[image] [image]

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure it now has something to do with UVs because I unwrapped the leaves again and the leaves were messed up. Is there like a short way to do this? When I join the leaves and the tree the UV resets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i get rid of these black shadows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77952/how-do-i-get-rid-of-these-black-shadows)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the shadows disappeared but i cant see the leaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well.  I started with the tree sapling, then added the leaves - like you did with alpha - same thing - after converting and removing the particle system, then joining, the leaves would not show in rendered mode.

I noticed that the sapling was generated wit it's own UV Map - "Orco" - once I deleted that UV Map, the join worked as expected.

I was pulling my hair out for a good while, and I don't have much to work with.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use both UV Maps, then in the material compositor, you will need to add a uv map node (Shift A...Input UV Map), then select the appropriate uv map to apply to the leaf object.  It appears that when you join two objects - each with their own uv map, the last selected object during the join operation - if it has a uv map, it is the default that is applied unless you specify otherwise with a uv map node.