# What is causing these black spots and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: rendering

[image][image]

What is causing the odd black spots and how do I get rid of them? Any ideas?

(Here's a picture of what I'm talking about circled in red)[image]

Comment: Hm...maybe a lighting issue? And by the way, how did you get the Minecraft model out of the game? (Just curious. :))

Comment: I used mineways and mcprep! Look up Black Plasma Studio's tutorial on minecraft animations for more info.

Comment: It could be z-fighting (so check overlapping faces) or, more likely, an insufficient number of transparent bounces. Could you show the material nodetree for the grass/shrub object=

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing! I didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: There, I added the nodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Transparent textured planes produce black artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026) and [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects/27719#27719)