# Cannot find way to make leaves seem to grow (sapling add-on)

Tags: animation, node-editor, sapling-addon

I need help! I am making a blender project where a tree grows. The trunk and  branches are working seamlessly (thanks to the bevel option), but I cannot find a way to make the leaves look like they are growing. So far, I have tried adding a transparency BSDF to make the leaves fade in, but I end up with weird black splotches while the leaves are supposed to be invisible:

[image: Rendered View:]

This is the node web I used: [image: The green section is the part that controls the look of the leaves, the blue part is the part that controls the transparency, and the pink part is the part I have keyframed.]

The green section is the part that controls the look of the leaves, the blue part is the part that controls the transparency, and the pink part is the part I have keyframed.

**If anybody can help me fix these splotches, or preferably even show me a better way of making the leaves appear, I will be very grateful!!!**

Thanks in advance,

*Imaginate*

Comment: increase transparency bounces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I changed the leaves' pivot point to individual origins, and keyframed the scale.

Comment: Note that pivot point is a point around which all objects in the Blender scenes are being operated, not just particular one.

Answer (score 0):

Make the leaves into a mesh. Then apply a shape key.
Apply a second one. Go into edit mode and smoothe the leaves until each one is so small you can’t see them 
After that you can go out of edit mode and drag the bar below the shape key up and down it looks kike the leaves are growing back and forth
You can apply key frames to this to achieve a “ growing” effect