# no transparency in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm sure someone already asked this, and yes, i googled it, but in cycles render, i do not know how to fix the transparency problem here. however, transparency works fine in blender render, so it is not my laptop not being able to support it.
[image]

i need to get rid of the black
i have a separate alpha png, but dont know how to apply it

Comment: if your PNG has a transparent background, plug the Image Texture with your image in the bottom entry of a Diffuse, plug this Diffuse in a Mix Shader, and plug the Mix Shader in the Material Output. Now plug a Transparent BSDF (100% white) in the top entry of the Mix Shader, and plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture in the Factor of the Mix Shader. It should work

Comment: This might not be an answer for the general transparency problem, but there is an Addon called "MCprep" that automaticaly sets up your exportet Minecraft-World for Cycles/Blender internal...

Comment: This is asked quite often. It's easier if you don't think in terms of transparency, but how to use a mask to control how two colors or shaders mix together (one of the shaders can be transparent). Read [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)

Comment: Another possibly related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026

Comment: i already used mcprep... only works for blender render for me...

Comment: i DO have an rgba, but no difference is shown between the rgb and rgba

Answer (score 1):

If your PNG has a transparent background, plug the Image Texture with your image in the bottom entry of a Diffuse, plug this Diffuse in a Mix Shader, and plug the Mix Shader in the Material Output. Now plug a Transparent BSDF (100% white) in the top entry of the Mix Shader, and plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture in the Factor of the Mix Shader. It should work

[image]

Comment: does not help me at all... still showing black in the texture.

Comment: are you sure your PNG have a transparent background?

Comment: i didnt say that. i said i also have an alpha png to render transparent stuff

Comment: also, i can obfuscate to get rid of the black, but its a hassle

Comment: maybe share a file with just the object so that we can check (and pack the PNG)

Comment: ill send u a zip of the entire project... be prepared for a minecraft one...

Answer (score -3):

Need to turn on "Transparent" on the render settings panel.

[image]

Comment: The problem is with surface transparency - that setting only affects render result background transparency.

Comment: please remove this answer... i would delete it if i could