# smoke + world volume scatter issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, effects

I have a volume scatter in my world settings at .1, and while trying to use a simple quicksmoke I'm getting black artifacts around the effect

[image]

white artifacts using branched path tracing

[image]

the whole thing is even more noticable when putting some emission on the fog. easily recreated by adding a volume scatter in the world settings, and simply making a quicksmoke.

Comment: try increasing the transparent bounces. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026

Comment: thanks Cegaton! I tried cranking them up but since it's volumetrics that didn't do much. However, the issue isn't existent in 2.79b only in the experimental builds, latest 2.79 and 2.8. So I just rebuilt my scene and am using the stable release to be on the safe side.