# Particle System Problem on Blender 2.79

Tags: particles

I want to make grass field with particle system but when i try that i get black shading  where the grasses close to each other. If i set emission number to low (for example 25) there is no problem but when i up i get this result. What should i do?
Thank you very much.[image]

Comment: Please show two screen captures and label them as successful/good and unsucessful/bad or something equivalent so we can easily understand what your problem is.

Comment: is the grass a mesh or a plane that uses a transparent texture? Maybe related: [transparent textured planes produce black artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts)

Comment: It is transparent plane but i fixed my problem by set to transparency to high number on render tab light path section.