# Blender 2.8 Cycles - Winter landscape, weird artefacts in few of the cut-out trees

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I come across an issue when rendering tree particles.

All of my trees in the attached image are from the source tree. The source tree is free of alpha mask problems. As one can see, most of them show up perfectly fine.
Still, some show strange black artefacts. Which seems weird as they are part of the same particle system.

Any suggestions? I appreciate your help.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: You will need to increase the transparency bounces in the render settings.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts

Comment: Thanks Leander & Duarte. Btw, I had to bump it up considerably. 12 transparency bounces did not fix it...

Comment: 24 did fix it...