# Why there is this wired "black" in my transparent material as distance is far

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I've imported this word with bounch of flowers. I've thecked the materal, the UV and it looks fine. But somehow, there is this wired "black". And this black even shows up when there is only the World backgroud lighting up the scene. I've tried Blender 2.83 LTS, and 2.9. Some issue.

I've tried theck the alpha of the texture image, I've tried change the alpha Clip/Hash/blend. Nothing really helps....

Here's the google drive link the of relavent blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18c9cKrDEY9RO4Lb4Ul1nDIsR4Ghq_3hI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you increase the amount of transparent light bounces in Render settings > Light Paths? See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of cumulated tranqparency is limited by this parameter here for Cycles:

[image]

For your scene, give it a value of 50 or so.

Comment: thx ! thx ! thx ! thx ! thx ! thx ! thx !