# How do I solve the problem of black surface forming on an object with 0 alpha transparency adjusted in cycle mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

In order to give the effect of disappearing the product through video, i made the **alpha 0 in the cycle mode to give transparency**.
[image]
When I proceed the rendering, **it's not completely transparent also black surfaces are occured**, and I've tried this and that, but I'm asking because it doesn't work.

**I'd like to ask if there is any way to get rid of this black surfaces and set it to a completely transparent state.**

The current setting is as follows.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023

Comment: Maybe you're lookin for "film" render options? In render property panel, under "film", check "transparent"

Answer (score 4):

Increase your transparency bounces in *Render Settings*. I think you don't have enough bounces to make it through the object all the way .

[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)