# Why do these particles generated by png images have a black background?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, image, transparency

the instance object is look great.

[image]

but the particle is black

[image]

---

I tried to tune  light paths → total and transparent to 24 even 1024，its look better but still black

---

This is the render setup and material.

[image]
[image]

The latest discovery is that when I enter the edit mode of the instance object, the particles appear normal.

[image]

by the way , I tried the method in the link, but it didn't work

Comment: pls upload blend file

Comment: <There was an internal error attempting to complete your request. >so i cant upload my file

Comment: U can use any cloud platform like google drive, Dropbox….

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rBKWThutOqdjBND7pNxF0DKs-qW24M4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I render your image I certainly start to see better results as I drastically crank up *Max Bounces* in *Light Paths* for cycles.  I stopped at 60 because rendering time became excessive on my workstation.

[image]

If your actually going to simulate and render to a motion image file, this begs a compromise, if you cannot tolerate such a long total rendering time.

Firstly, I find a way to reduce Emission Number from 120 downwards.  If the camera remains static, when you can scale your X axis of your particle plane so that you don't loose too much.

Then play a bit with the Light Paths, Max Bounces.

As an alternative, I tried out a smoke domain (Object >> Quick Effects) that uses more realistic physics.  I lowered the Density on the emitter plane object from 1.0 to 0.03 and the density on the auto-material from 5.0 to 0.2 and made the color redder instead of gray.

[image]

for this type of image that will also change as you render frames.

[image]

You may want to enable the Dissolve feature in the Domain if there is too much gas in later frames.  Or you may want to make the emission into a Geometry instead of Inflow, and enable all Border Collisions.

Here is a fragment of your file with the Smoke/Gas approach.  [image]  Deleted most else as blend-exchange uploads must be small.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I will try the method you provide！

Comment: @isu -- looks like I forgot to include a link to my solution file.  I have updated my answer and also added another idea in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: Thanks again！：)