# Hair texture looks different in Render Preview than Material Preview in Cycle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, hair

This texture based hair, looks different in render preview than in material preview in cycle.

I would like the final rendering to look the same as in the material preview.

I have tried different settings and I’ve looked for solution everywhere without success.
I’m using Blender 3.6

I have not created the texture myself but it looks good in material preview in cycle and in Eevee engine.

Thanks

[image: Hair texture problem]

Comment: Material Preview always uses Eevee for speed whereas Render Preview will use the render engine that you have set in the properties panel. Change  the render engine to Eevee if you want your final render to look the same as in the Material Preview view.

Comment: Thank you John,
The thing is that I’m working in a scene that required the cycle engine for convenience. Do you mean there is no way to get the hair looking the same in cycle engine rendering?

Comment: These so-called hair cards use a transparency. If you want to use Cycles you need to increase the light bounce value for transparency because it stacks a lot. If the value if too low you will see black areas. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275900/107598

Comment: Thank you very much @Blunder 
I’ve changed the transparent setting to 124 as you suggested and the hair is looking great now in render preview in cycle. Thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts