At different angles the grass turns black during the render preview

Changing alpha settings doesn't help. In the preview material, the grass looks correct. The blackness in the render appears precisely when I look at the grass through the grass

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects

I would especially look at Duarte's second link for a solution, but the accepted answer there confuses transmission with transparency, read my comment under that answer and see my own answer to that question.

@GordonBrinkmann Thank you, the solution was very simple
