Solid Black Spots on Transparent textures
I'm trying to render this hair but there are weird obvious black spots that doesn't appear in solid mode.
This only happens in render mode and I've also tried merging by distance but no results, helps are appreciated!




Maybe in the Render panel > Light Paths > increase the Transparent value?

Works like a charm! Thank you so much!!!!!

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts
