# Multiple Alpha Meshes Stacked Turning Black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, transparency

So uh, I'm rather new to the Cycles Engine, and while I've been able to find a lot of it out, I'm struggling with one specific thing.
The center of this model I'm working on, (Not my model by the way) has a kind of ball of lightning in the center, comprised of multiple plane meshes kind of randomly rotated within the model. However, attempting to recreate this in cycles is giving... odd results.

As you can see, the alpha is getting applied properly, but as multiple of the meshes layer up, the meshes kind of, create a blackness again, as if they were created without the alpha layer. But as you can see, the edges of the lightning, where there isn't another mesh behind it, is still transparent.

[image]

You can observe it more here with this tower of planes, after five or so, they suddenly turn black.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the material in the node editor by the way. https://i.gyazo.com/5e42f53885e115a5e9b708a0ecee9ce1.png

Comment: Well actually I found the answer, here

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects

So that's useful. Leaving it here for future reference if anyone needs it.