# How i can make glass material with increasing amount of sampling

Tags: glass

Hi guys i m having problem with blender. In cycles render when i increase amount of sampling glass material getting black and its glass property disappearing can someone help for this problem thanks

Comment: Add picture of your output

Comment: increase transparency bounces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvPeA.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects)

Comment: In Cycles, go to your Render Settings > Light Paths > Transparency: Increase the Max from the default 8 until you can see through your glass planes.