# Black areas in minecraft render when using Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, light, transparency

I've been doing some minecraft renders using Jmc2Obj and McPrep, and have encountered no issues up until this point. However, I think I accidentally changed something in the settings, and now there are black areas around the grass (Which uses a mixture of transparency and color shaders). If anybody has some fixes to suggest, that would be lovely. Thank you[image: y]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have my light paths set very high.

Comment: increase Transparency bounces.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your material as well as your material settings?