# How to fix shadow artifacts on a simple planme

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

I have a simple rectangular cube mesh that renders correctly in Eevee but has strange shadow effects on the top and sides when I render in Cycles. I've confirmed there is no Custom Split Normals Data, the normals are facing outward, and there are no other objects in the scene that could be casting shadows. The top pic is with Eevee and the bottom is with Cycles. I've also attached the project folder. Any ideas?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyn9pv7r8cycvk9/Skybox.zip?dl=0

[image: No Artifact with Eevee]
[image: Artifact in Cycles]

Comment: Hi could you first go to file>external data>pack all into blend and then send the file please instead of sharing a ZIP file

Comment: It seems to be related to floating-point precision. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207480/floating-point-precision-problem-with-transparency

Comment: Applying the scale helps a lot, as does moving the object closer to the world origin.

Answer (score 1):

The Origin of your object is problematically far away from your mesh; as [Ron Jensen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/33589/ron-jensen) said, it's floating point precision.

Apply the location of the object, or perform Origin to geometry and you'll be fine.

Comment: That got rid of the artifacts, thanks! Your a lifesaver!