# Alpha images appear completely black

Tags: transparency

I'm having a strange issue where alpha images appear as completely black. It doesn't seem consistent and i'm not sure why. Anyone got an idea?[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are in Eevee you need to make sure that in the Properties panel > Material > Settings, you've enabled the Blend Mode > Alpha Blend

Comment: If you are using cycles increase transparent bounces. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects

Comment: @susu brilliant, thank you mate.

Comment: @user115601 for future questions please state what render engine you are using. Eevee and cycles work differently.