# Some of my duplicated images with transparent background are rendered black as I add them further back in my scene

Tags: transparency

I have stacked tree planes with a transparency background. The duplicated rendered normally until I added them further back in my scene. Some of them turned black when rendered. It could be because of the alignment. I looked up but didn't find a solution. Blender 2.79 cycles
Thank you for your help.

[image: tree planes with transparency background]

Comment: Hi Nathalie, we need "some" information from you so that we can effectively help you. A screenshot is good - but not enough. Blender is pretty complex and there might be several reasons for this. If you want that we can help, best way - just my opinion - is to provide your blend file so we can see all your settings you did and we can reproduce your problem.  You can do this here: https://blend-exchange.com/. Another possibility is to provide screenshots of all relevant and important settings you made that we need.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SMYAQ77J" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SMYAQ77J/)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I found the solution in the answer provided https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects