# Images as planes gives black boxes with many instances

Tags: rendering, materials, particles, image

I'm trying to make a forest with Images as Planes, which gives some weird black boxes in the render. I have created a Hair Particle System with 5000 particles. In the Render Settings I have set Light Paths / Transparent to 256. Still the black boxes appear and I don't know how to get rid of them. What do I have to do differently? Thanks for your help.

[Blender File](https://we.tl/t-JdyhIeWHoi)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your issue is Z-fighting ... overlapping faces (faces share the same location).

You can see glittering already in *Solid View* mode. Blacks appears also in front planes.

Try to lower number of particles ... If you can't avoid overlapping from location - try **Randomize Rotation,** just a bit so the planes are crossing, but doesn't lay on each other.

[image]
Specularity set to zero.