# Alpha transparency on curve on points is showing black

Tags: materials, transparency

I have 2 objects that are driven identically for the nodes that are involved with pumping out the material. The image on the left is the **Material Preview**. The image on the right is the **Render**

The icosphere rainbow is a single object and is rendering correctly.

The projected donut/whisk looking object is a result of curves on points. I can tell that I've captured the surface points correctly because when I allow the gradient to cover the entire object, the gradient stretches on the longer stalks in the back. When doing it naively, the gradient follows the "water level."
[image: material preview left / render right]

Here is the geo-nodes for the broken one
[image]

Here is the geo-nodes for the sphere
[image]

They have identical materials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects) Hard to tell from just the screenshots, so maybe this is caused by too few bounces.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!! Thank you @GordonBrinkmann!

Comment: Now that it works, I need a render farm to deal with it :(

Comment: Well, sorry - this is not the place for suggestions of this kind ;)