# "Transparency Clipping" when working with multiple transparent objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

Unsure how to describe this. I am currently working on a particle cannon effect with a core and 3 lightning "tubes" around it. Take a look:

First, The elements:
[image: Elements]

The inner core is a simple cylinder, distorted by a noise texture. **I made sure that there is no clipping in the mesh.**
If rendered by themselves, as seen in this first picture, there is no issue.

The Material for the core:

[image: Core Material]

The Material for the Lightning bolts

[image: Lightning bolts Material]

**When you render them together...**

[image: Issue]

It appears, that as soon as two or more of the "creases" of the inner core overlap, the tubes that should be transparent get rendered.
Is there any possibility to "increase" the threshold or otherwise solve this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try increasing the settings for Transparency bounces in the Light paths section.

Comment: Changing the render settings does not help. I tried every setting possible.
Edit: No I didn't. That helped. Thanks!

Comment: Potentially related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! Feeling stupid now haha.