# Transparency on complex objects in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

Ok so Ive been a user of blender now for 7 - 6 years and I absolutely love the program especially cycles but ive had a problem for at least 2 years of me using cycles when I give a complex shape a transparency node (just the transparency to the material out put) I get strange outlines of the object on screen this interferes with my  render quite a bit EX: when I'm rendering something using particles and I use a complex shape to emulate the emission of particles I have to make the object that's emitting them transparent doing so though causes a black outline of the object and this is quite the annoyance.[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Increase the transparency bounces read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes/18859#18859 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects/27719#27719