# Dark areas on transparent planes

Tags: rendering, materials

I got a little problem with transparency in Blender.

If I load a texture and use it as foliage, for example gras, I recieve a visual bug. Check it out.[image]
Even if I use transparent maps or seperate alpha maps it happens. Do you know how to solve this?
(This is my gras-texture) [image]
For any sugestions I would be very glad.

Comment: increase the number of transparency bounces. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects/27719#27719 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes