# I get an error with a object when I try to make it transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, transparency

I made a hat that would later end up in a later scene.

[image]

so I made it transparent until the scene

[image]

But somehow its messed up when I made it transparent. I get a big black blob from the hat

[image]

I removed thee doubles, but there is still the same problem. just it's a smaller black.

[image]

Its not supposed to show up at all. what am I doing. I saved and restarted it, thinking it was a bug, but i got the same thing

Comment: Increase the number of samples for transparency. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to eliminate Cycles artifacts with many overlapping volumes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whats happening here, but i might know a work around. Instead of making it transparent you could just stop it from rendering. You do this by hovering over the render button and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

This will place a key frame (it should light up when one is placed). Now just click it while on the keyframe you placed and place another key frame where you want it to render.

[image]

Hope this helps