# Fading multiple objects at once in Cycles turning black

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, shader-nodes

I'm using Blender 3.0.1 with Cycles and trying to fade multiple objects in and out slowly. All the objects have the same image texture.

I have watched countless videos about it and they all say the same thing, to add a *Transparent BSDF* and a *Mix Shader* node to the shading tab. Which it works, but with multiple objects it creates black chunks and weird shadows.

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there something else I have to do with the nodes?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18857/599 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts

Comment: Thank you so much Duarte.