# Tree branches showing shadows off each other, ruining their transparency

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

I have a dead tree asset that has branches which are a jumble of planes that have transparency. I want the shadow of the tree but I don't want the branches shadows to expose the transparency(and show the plane.

[image]

I am using Cycles in Blender 3.4.1

During research I found that it is impossible to disable shadows for a specific material/texture, or disable its ability to catch shadows. I think that is a way I could solve this issue if there is a way to do it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes