# CYCLES alpha issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I plugged a mask texture into the alpha slot of the 4.0 principle BSDF, which is diplayed normally, white part of the texture was shown and black part was transparent, however, when there're folds, as displayed in the attached image, the folded part became pure black instead of transparent.

I have tried 3.6 as well, didn't work.

[image]

Comment: seems like when one transparent material is layered on top of another transparent material it became pure black

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts