Overlapping material mapping on plants comes out black - possible z fighting
I have downloaded some plants from GlobePlants,but when I apply the materials and alpha to the flowers, some of the densely packed areas come out black. Could someone tell me what is happening and how I can fix this?
I have tried different alphas, changing the light passes, the camera min. and max, as well as importing from rhino instead.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/how-to-eliminate-cycles-artifacts-with-many-overlapping-volumes
